# Optimization issue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

**TASK:**
Take an integer named **n** from user. Take **n** times **name-phone number** input from user then take names again. If names that you entered second time is in the list print **name=phone number** related. Else print **Not found**.

**Example input:**

[image: input_example]

**Example output:**

[image]

The problem is that I wrote a working code. But if you pass to `n` a value that is too big, the code takes too much time to solve it. It's a challenge question so website that I'm working on doesn't accept my code and wants me to optimize the code. I tried a few different ways to optimize it however none of them solved that issue.

**My Code:**

```
n = int(input())

d = {}
for x in range(n):
    key_value = input().split()
    d[key_value[0]]= key_value[1]
    
lofnames = []
for name in range(n):
    name = input()
    lofnames.append(name)

for name in lofnames:
    flag = False
    for key in d:
        if key == name:
            print(f"{key}={d[key]}")
            flag = True
    if flag == False:
        print("Not found")
```

Comment: If n is a very large number, and you're timing out, perhaps you could find a way to cut down on the number of loops in your code, or things you do in those loops. Google around for optimising python for speed, I know there are helpful pages out there, I've found them :b

Comment: I tried to add break under the **flag = True**, but it didn't work =( .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function's runtime complexity is `O(N^2)` and not `O(N)` as the site probably wants it to be, due to the nested `for` loop you have. You can cut down on this complexity by not iterating through the dictionary and instead using its property as a hashtable of an `O(1)` lookup time. Consider using a `try-except` block to except `KeyError`s in the dictionary for the key `name` that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're manually iterating over the dictionary's keys, performing an O(n) operation for each name that you want to check. You could just use the `in` operator to check for a name's existence in an O(1) operation:

```py
for name in lofnames:
    if name in d:
        print(f"{key}={d[key]}")
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

Comment: Thank you helped a lot!